# Random crash on UINavigationController push segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, pushviewcontroller

I have an issue that seems to happen about once a week in our enterprise iOS app.  Everything works fine, and then randomly I see an error for

> "Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'toOrderView'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController."

Here's the full crash report:

> Thread : Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
>   0  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018588022c _exceptionPreprocess
>   1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001974500e4 objc_exception_throw
>   2  UIKit                          0x000000018a8cf934 -[UIStoryboardPushSegue destinationContainmentContext]
>   3  Foundation                     0x0000000186782fc4 _NSFireTimer
>   4  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185837e78 _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
>   5  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185837b28 __CFRunLoopDoTimer
>   6  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185835574 __CFRunLoopRun
>   7  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185760f74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>   8  GraphicsServices               0x000000018f0936fc GSEventRunModal
>   9  UIKit                          0x000000018a362d94 UIApplicationMain
>   10 MyLync                         0x000000010015a8bc main (main.m:15)
>   11 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000197afaa08 start

Again, this problem doesn't occur 99% of the time, but every once in a while the error crashes my application.  This is the most common transition in the application as it is the primary page our users visit.  I have even logged how many times the push transition occurs per machine and it gets reported when a crash happens, but it works greater than 99 out of 100 times.  And it only occurs on some machines, as some users have 0 instances of this crash. 
I am completely confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Also of note, I have created plenty of apps for our organization, and this is the **ONLY** one that has ever had this problem, although almost all of them utilize the navigation controller object.
I can post code or whatever else, but like I said, since it almost always works, I'm looking for a reason why it won't for that less than 1% of the time.
Here's whats in the prepareForSegue block:

```
if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"toOrderView"]){
    LYNViewOrderViewController *vovc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vovc.orderNumber = sendingOrder.orderNo;
}
```

And here's the calling code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (tableView == tblCredits) {
        sendingOrder = creditArray[indexPath.row];
    }else{
        sendingOrder = orderArray[indexPath.row];
    }
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toOrderView" sender:self];
}
```

There is not an issue where the sending order is not populated, I have already checked for that.

Comment: how is the segue called? by a timer ? or by a normal button press ?

Comment: @Mr.T The user presses on the order they want to see from a tableview row.  That orderID then gets passed via the push segue to the ViewOrder page.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I just received a crash log with the same issue and there is definitely a navigation controller behind the views I am trying to push. It also works 99%+ of the time so I don't really know where to start! My gut feel says the navigation controller is getting dealloc prematurely for some reason (maybe after the app has been sitting idle in the background for a while) but no idea how to actually prove it or even reproduce the problem!

Comment: No, unfortunately I have had no luck trying to determine what is happening when this occurs.  I had the same sort of gut feeling that something inside the navigation controller was having issues or that something was getting dealloc'd out of order, but I have no way to test it out.

Comment: No problems I'll come back to this thread if I have any news and hopefully you'll be able to do the same. Thanks!